# Sort a list of Class Instances Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of class instances -

```
x = [<iteminstance1>,...]
```

among other attributes the class has `score` attribute. How can I sort the items in  ascending order based on this parameter?

**EDIT**: The `list` in python has something called `sort`. Could I use this here? How do I direct this function to use my `score` attribute?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
import operator
sorted_x = sorted(x, key=operator.attrgetter('score'))
```

if you want to sort x in-place, you can also:

```
x.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('score'))
```

Comment: wow! is it that simple!! Just checked. It is :)

Comment: Welcome to Python! For sake of completness: the "key" parameter to srot functions/methods accepts a function as its parameter. The operator module provides usefull functions to tasks that are ordinarily done by the language Syntax itself - like an "add" function to do the same the " + " token does in the language, and in this case the attrgetter to do the same the " . " connector does in the syntax. Other parameters to "key" can be inplace functions defined with "lambda". In this case, sorted_x = sorted(x, lambda x: x.score)) - would have worked as well. The given example is better, though.

Comment: I'm not sure using `attrgetter` is better. Lambdas seems to be just as fast, and look cleaner IMO.

Comment: This is just great. Thanks for the question and the answer likewise!

Comment: sometimes python's simplicity scares me

Comment: That wasn't working for me, this worked better: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-sort-objects-of-a-class-in-Python.php

Use: `sorted(list, function)`

Answer (score 229):

In addition to the solution you accepted, you could also implement the special `__lt__()` ("less than") method on the class. The `sort()` method (and the `sorted()` function) will then be able to compare the objects, and thereby sort them. This works best when you will only ever sort them on this attribute, however.

```
class Foo(object):

     def __init__(self, score):
         self.score = score

     def __lt__(self, other):
         return self.score < other.score

l = [Foo(3), Foo(1), Foo(2)]
l.sort()
```

Comment: This is particularly useful if you don't have access to sorted function. This happens when sorted is called by some other modules such as the standard library modules. Example - `priorityqueue` in `queue` calls sorted for the items you supply.

Comment: What if we have instances with 2 params like Foo['abc',3]

Comment: @BimleshSharma Then write your `__lt__` method according to how you want your instances to compare, e.g. `return (self.text, self.num) < (other.text, other.num)`.

Comment: It took me a moment to figure that `list.sort()` sorts the existing list (and returns `NoneType`), while `sorted(list)` returns the sorted copy of the list.

Comment: Also very useful is you have seriously nested data. Having something of type `[(Foo,Bar)]` makes something like `sort()` really tricky otherwise.