# Having an object array in python, how can I classify its elements by an attribute?

Tags: python, oop, grouping

In Python, is there a function that classifies and orders an array of objects by an attribute?

Example:

```
class Book:
    """A Book class"""
    def __init__(self,name,author,year):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
        self.year = year

hp1 = Book("Harry Potter and the Philosopher's stone","J.k Rowling",1997)
hp2 = Book("Harry Potter and the chamber of secretse","J.k Rowling",1998)
hp3 = Book("Harry Potter and the Prisioner of Azkaban","J.k Rowling",1999)

#asoiaf stands for A Song of Ice and Fire
asoiaf1 = Book("A Game of Thrones","George R.R Martin",1996)
asoiaf2 = Book("A Clash of Kings","George R.R Martin",1998)

hg1 = Book("The Hunger Games","Suzanne Collins",2008)
hg2 = Book("Catching Fire","Suzanne Collins",2009)
hg3 = Book("Mockingjaye","Suzanne Collins",2010);

books = [hp3,asoiaf1,hp1,hg1,hg2,hp2,asoiaf2,hg3]
#disordered on purpose

organized_by_autor = magic_organize_function(books,"author")
```

Does the magic_organize_function exist? Otherwise, what would it be?

Comment: So do you want to group-by and sort by author?

Comment: The `sorted()` function in Python takes a `key` parameter. It is used to specify _how_ you want your list sorted. In your case you want to sort by the `author` attribute of each element in the list `books`: `organized_by_autor = sorted(books, lambda book: book.author)`

Comment: FWIW the `;` are superfluous. They don't do anything.

Comment: If the linked question doesn't solve your problem, let me know.

Comment: If the duplicate that @WayneWerner linked to is still not clear, I suggest taking at look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010322/sort-a-list-of-class-instances-python) post.

Comment: @WayneWerner I was gonna suggest he use groupby after sorting for that 'classification' he asked, but now I'm gonna go to sleep, so if you reopen, help him out

Comment: @WayneWerner the linked question wasn't what I was looking for, I was looking for the itertools.groupby function, but thank you anyways.

Comment: @EduardoAndrésCastilloPerera I've re-opened your question - you should accept Mike's answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer, since it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting by author is one way:

```
sorted_by_author = sorted(books, key=lambda x: x.author)
for book in sorted_by_author:
    print(book.author)
```

Output:

```
George R.R Martin
George R.R Martin
J.k Rowling
J.k Rowling
J.k Rowling
Suzanne Collins
Suzanne Collins
Suzanne Collins
```

You can also nicely group by author using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

organized_by_author = groupby(sorted_by_author, key=lambda x: x.author)

for author, book_from_author in organized_by_author:
    print(author)
    for book in book_from_author:
        print('    ', book.name)
```

Output:

```
George R.R Martin
     A Game of Thrones
     A Clash of Kings
J.k Rowling
     Harry Potter and the Prisioner of Azkaban
     Harry Potter and the Philosopher's stone
     Harry Potter and the chamber of secretse
Suzanne Collins
     The Hunger Games
     Catching Fire
     Mockingjaye
```

**Note**: You need to feed `groupby` the sorted `sorted_by_author`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!