# Sort a group of Classes by default property

Tags: vba, excel, class, sorting, icomparable

TL;DR:

**Is there any way to pass a class collection/list to a *library* sorting algorithm, and get it to return a sorted list (preferably by a named/default class property)?**

I've recently been learning some Python, and was impressed by the `Sorted()` function, which can sort any iterable. For numbers this is straightforward, for classes however, it is possible to assign a comparison method [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010558/6609896). The method tells comparison operators how to compare 2 instances of the class. Amongst other things it allows you to use builtin sorting algorithms to sort a collection of the class.

In VBA I've been half successful in mimicking this. By setting a class' [default member](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx) `Attribute`, you can use comparison operators (`<`,`=`,`>=`, etc.) on classes directly. Take the example class:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "defaultProp"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Private randVal As Single

Public Property Get DefaultValue() As Single
    Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0
    DefaultValue = randVal
End Property

Private Property Let DefaultValue(ByVal value As Single)
    randVal = value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    DefaultValue = Rnd()
End Sub
```

Two instances of this class can be compared:

```
 Dim instance1 As New defaultProp
 Dim instance2 As New defaultProp
 Debug.Print instance1.DefaultValue > instance2.DefaultValue
 Debug.Print instance1 > instance2 'exactly equivalent, as the DefaultValue has the correct Attribute
```

And if I was implementing a VBA sort algorithm that can sort values, there should be no problem sorting classes by default value*. However I would prefer to use a builtin/library sorting algorithm (for the same reasons anyone would; clarity, efficiency, proper error handling etc.)

<sub>*One of [these algorithms](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=473677) would work for that, although must be modified to switch the entire class round, not the value of it (by adding `Set`s)</sub>

Since VBA comparison operators have no issue, I assumed the same would be true for whatever the library was using. However when I tried with an [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Sub testArrayList()
    Dim arr As Object
    Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    ' Initialise the ArrayList, for instance by generating random values
    Dim i As Long
    Dim v As defaultProp

    For i = 1 To 5
        Set v = New defaultProp
        arr.Add v 'no problem here
    Next i
    arr.Sort 'raises an error
End Sub
```

I get an error

> Failed to compare two elements in the array

So what's going on? Is it a flaw in my approach - is the default attribute not making it to the `ArrayList`? Or maybe the comparison operator in whatever language the library is written in is not as floopy-gloopy as the ones VBA and Python use? Any suggestions on more builtin sorting algorithms to try would be useful too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about the VBA comparison operators, `ArrayList` is a .NET class, so you're in the .NET world when you use it.

```
arr.Add v 'no problem here
```

You're adding instances of the `defaultProp` class; it doesn't matter that you have a default property on the type, .NET doesn't care about default properties. If you want to sort `DefaultValue` values, then do `arr.Add v.DefaultValue` or `arr.Add (v)` - then your `ArrayList` will contain items of type `Single`, which it knows how to sort.

In order for `ArrayList.Sort` to work with instances of your custom class, its items need to implement the `IComparable` interface, which is the case for `System.Int32` (i.e. `Long` in VBA), `System.String` and every other primitive .NET types, and I *think* the VBA primitive types would indeed marshal correctly through .NET interop - but not custom classes.

Try adding a reference to **mscorlib.tlb**, and then in the `defaultProp` class module, specify this (you can't implement an interface that's defined in a late-bound library):

```
Implements IComparable
```

Then implement the interface - should look something like this (use the codepane dropdowns to make sure to get the correct signature - **don't just copy-paste this snippet**:

```
Private Function IComparable_CompareTo(ByVal obj As Variant) As Long
    Dim other As defaultProp
    Set other = obj
    ' return Less than zero (-1) if this object 
    ' is less than the object specified by the CompareTo method.

    ' return Zero (0) if this object is equal to the object 
    ' specified by the CompareTo method.

    ' return Greater than zero (1) if this object is greater than 
    ' the object specified by the CompareTo method.
End Function
```

Now that your custom class implements the interface `ArrayList.Sort` uses to determine how your `defaultProp` items relate to each other, I don't see a reason for it to fail.

Answer (score 4):

IMO, you are abusing things by mixing things cross the boundaries. You're using VBA's default properties (something I generally perceive as a bad practice), then you're using .NET's `ArrayList` and trying to `Sort` it.

I think it would be much more logical to see if you can implement `IComparable` on the VBA class and then let the `ArrayList` use the `IComparable` interface to compare an object against other by however you want it to compare, without using any default properties hacked.

Comment: Well as Mat's Mug points out, I don't think there is a way to implement sorting with an ArrayList without implementing `IComparable` (default properties don't help!) That was just a possible approach, but now I see there are other options

Answer (score 2):

If you add the DefaultValue to the `arr` it would work:

```
Sub testArrayList()
    '... code
    For i = 1 To 5
        Set v = New defaultProp
        arr.Add v.DefaultValue 
    Next i
    arr.Sort         
End Sub
```

Obviously the implementation of `.Sort` of `ArrayList` is a bit strange and does not like comparing objects and their default values (could not find the implementation of the `Sort()` method). Although, this would work flawlessly:

```
For i = 1 To 5
    Set v = New defaultProp
    arr.Add v
Next i    
Debug.Print arr(1) > arr(2)
```

This is a possible implementation of sorting, that would work for the `arr` object as expected. However, it is not part of the `ArrayList` library:

```
Public Function varBubbleSort(varTempArray As Object) As Object

    Dim varTemp                 As Object
    Dim lngCounter              As Long
    Dim blnNoExchanges          As Boolean

    Do
        blnNoExchanges = True
        For lngCounter = 0 To varTempArray.Count - 2
            If varTempArray(lngCounter) > varTempArray(lngCounter + 1) Then
                blnNoExchanges = False
                Set varTemp = varTempArray(lngCounter)
                varTempArray(lngCounter) = varTempArray(lngCounter + 1)
                varTempArray(lngCounter + 1) = varTemp
            End If
        Next lngCounter

    Loop While Not (blnNoExchanges)
    Set varBubbleSort = varTempArray

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Function

End Function
```

But the sorting is ok:

[image]

Comment: Ah, but then I have an array of values, not of classes. I'd like to sort the class list by some value, but actually move the entire class objects around

Comment: So, the comparison operators work when the classes are added to an ArrayList (your 2nd bit of code) - but the sort on them directly doesn't work? Any idea of a workaround, as it's the objects I need to sort, not their default values (although of course you could map the latter back onto the former, but that detracts from using a library sort in the first place)

Comment: @Greedo - I suppose that it is simply the implementation of `.Sort()` that is made this way. E.g., probably in it they are using `LBound` and `UBound` and it is breaking the function. I am just guessing here, as far as I cannot see it.

Comment: FWIW for reference.... [ArrayList's Sort implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,697)