# Algorithm for filtering a list

Tags: vba, algorithm, arraylist, filter, time-complexity

I have implemented what I think is a pretty rubbish method for filtering a `System.Collections.ArrayList` in VBA. The code takes a list and an item/comparison value to filter out. It loops through the list and removes matching items. It then restarts the loop (because you can't `For Each` and `.Remove` at the same time)

```
Public Sub Filter(ByVal testValue As Object, ByVal dataSet As ArrayList)
'testValue and the items in `dataSet` all Implement IComparable from mscorlib.dll
'This allows comparing objects for equality
'i.e. obj1.CompareTo(obj2) = 0 is equivalent to obj1 = obj2
    Dim item As IComparable
    Dim repeat As Boolean
    repeat = False
    For Each item In dataSet
        If item.CompareTo(testValue) = 0 Then   'or equiv; If item = testValue
            dataSet.Remove item
            repeat = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next item
    If repeat Then Filter testValue, dataSet 
End Sub
```

Why *rubbish*?

Let's say the list is `X` elements long and contains `Y` items which match the filtering criteria, with `X>Y`. As far as I can tell, the best case performance is `O(X)`, when all the `Y`s are bunched at the start. The worst case is when all the `Y`s are bunched at the end. In that case the algorithm requires `(X-Y)*Y` lookup operations, max when `Y=X/2`, so `O(X^2)`

This is poor compared to the simple `O(X)` algorithm of stepping along and removing when you get to a match, but not breaking the loop. Yet I have no idea how to implement it. **Is there a way to improve the performance of this filter?**

Comment: Great question  though it does feel like a code review style question. Also, what is the datatype within the arrayList?

Comment: isn't this VB.NET?

Comment: @QHarr The list contains objects which `Implement IComparable` which is some interface from `mscorlib.dll`. However they could just as easily be strings or numbers and the check would then be `=` rather than `.CompareTo() = 0`. PS Thanks, although this is only a condensed snippet of my code and felt it was more suited here than CR - I thought CR was only for long stuff?

Comment: @DisplayName No, I'm doing this in `Excel-VBA`, with a reference to `mscorlib.dll` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777386/6609896)

Comment: I think you are much better off with a for loop going from i= 1 to dataSet.Count and then: if (match condition) then dataset.RemoveAt(i) and decrease i by 1, so that you don’t miss a record.

Comment: CR requires the entire code (not about size but about context. Code in situ) rather than the MCVE. So yeah...maybe snippet better here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not do something like the following, which is O(n) I believe:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemItems()

    Const TARGET_VALUE As String = "dd"
    Dim myList As Object
    Set myList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    myList.Add "a"
    myList.Add "dd"
    myList.Add "a"
    myList.Add "a"
    myList.Add "a"
    myList.Add "dd"
    myList.Add "a"
    myList.Add "a"
    myList.Add "dd"
    myList.Add "a"
    myList.Add "a"

    Dim i As Long
    For i = myList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If myList(i) = TARGET_VALUE Then myList.Remove myList(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

For complexity information see this discussion:

[Asymptotic complexity of .NET collection classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851949/asymptotic-complexity-of-net-collection-classes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

And if [this](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/.NET-Big-O-Algorithm-Complexity-Cheat-Sheet/blob/master/Cheat%20Sheet.html) is to be believed (.NET-Big-O-Algorithm-Complexity-Cheat-Sheet):

[image]

Note: I rendered the HTML with https://htmledit.squarefree.com/

### **Edit:**

***Caveat - I am not a CS graduate. This was playing around. I am sure there are debates to be had about what data type is being handled, distributions etc.....Improvements welcomed***

The .Net table above showed deletion from **HashTable** being on average `O(1)` for deleting, versus `O(n)` for ArrayList, so I generated 100,000 rows randomly from values `{"a","b","c"}`. I then used that as my fixed test set for the following results.

[image: Runs]

[image: Test set proportions]

**Code for test runs (please be gentle!)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function getFrequency Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "QueryPerformanceFrequency" (cyFrequency As Currency) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function getTickCount Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "QueryPerformanceCounter" (cyTickCount As Currency) As Long

Public Sub TestingArrayList()
    Const TARGET_VALUE = "a"
    Dim aList As Object
    Set aList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim arr()
    arr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value '<== Reads in 100000 value

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) '50000
        aList.Add arr(i, 2)
    Next i

    Debug.Print aList.Contains(TARGET_VALUE)

    Dim StartTime As Double

    StartTime = MicroTimer()

    For i = aList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
       If aList(i) = TARGET_VALUE Then aList.Remove aList(i)
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Removal from array list took: " & Round(MicroTimer - StartTime, 3) & " seconds"
    Debug.Print aList.Contains(TARGET_VALUE)

End Sub

Public Sub TestingHashTable()
    Const TARGET_VALUE = "a"
    Dim hTable As Object
    Set hTable = CreateObject("System.Collections.HashTable")

    Dim arr()
    arr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value '<== Reads in 100000 value

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) '50000
        hTable.Add i, arr(i, 2)
    Next i

    Debug.Print hTable.ContainsValue(TARGET_VALUE)

    Dim StartTime As Double

    StartTime = MicroTimer()

    For i = hTable.Count To 1 Step -1
       If hTable(i) = TARGET_VALUE Then hTable.Remove i
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Removal from hash table took: " & Round(MicroTimer - StartTime, 3) & " seconds"
    Debug.Print hTable.ContainsValue(TARGET_VALUE)

End Sub

Public Function MicroTimer() As Double

    Dim cyTicks1 As Currency
    Static cyFrequency As Currency

    MicroTimer = 0

    If cyFrequency = 0 Then getFrequency cyFrequency

    getTickCount cyTicks1

    If cyFrequency Then MicroTimer = cyTicks1 / cyFrequency
End Function
```

The above had what appeared to be a 0(1).

Simply looking at the removal process (removing other factors), the results were less conclusive, though again, my coding may be a factor!

[image: Deletion run]

**Revised code (removing other factors):**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestingComparison()

    Const RUN_COUNT As Long = 4

    Dim hTable As Object
    Dim aList As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, rowCount As Long
    Dim results() As Double

    Set hTable = CreateObject("System.Collections.HashTable")
    Set aList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim testSizes()
    testSizes = Array(100, 1000, 10000, 100000)  ', 1000000)
    ReDim results(0 To RUN_COUNT * (UBound(testSizes) + 1) - 1, 0 To 4)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")

        For i = LBound(testSizes) To UBound(testSizes)

            For k = 1 To RUN_COUNT

                For j = 1 To testSizes(i)
                    hTable.Add j, 1
                    aList.Add 1
                Next j

                Dim StartTime As Double, completionTime As Double

                StartTime = MicroTimer()

                For j = hTable.Count To 1 Step -1
                    hTable.Remove j
                Next j

                results(rowCount, 3) = Round(MicroTimer - StartTime, 3)
                results(rowCount, 0) = testSizes(i)
                results(rowCount, 1) = k

                StartTime = MicroTimer()

                For j = aList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    aList.Remove aList(j)
                Next j

                results(rowCount, 2) = Round(MicroTimer - StartTime, 3)

                hTable.Clear
                aList.Clear
                rowCount = rowCount + 1
            Next k

        Next i

        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(results, 1) + 1, UBound(results, 2)) = results

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am guessing you have deliberately avoided using a SortedList?

Comment: Yep, this seems to be a better way of doing it. That is assuming Enumerating an array List (`For...Each`) and Indexing (`myList(i)`) have the same algorithmic complexity, do you know? My gut feeling is that they'd both be `O(n^0)`, i.e. independent of the size of the array, with Indexing having a slightly larger overhead (if `ArrayLists` work like `Collections`). The overhead becomes negligible as n->large.

Comment: Why do you think I might want to use SortedList. The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) don't show any sort of builtin `Filter` method? What could I do with a `SortedList` that I can't with an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Forget that as sorted list won't allow for duplicate keys I believe.

Comment: Oh that's interesting; removal is `O(n)`. But I'm still not sure; are `For Each item In myList: Next item` and `For i = myList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1: Set item = myList(i): next i` both `O(n)` or is there some hidden complexity in enumeration I'm not aware of? Indexing is, as per your source, definitely `O(1)` so the latter approach is certainly `O(n)`

Comment: Hopefully a CS person will come along and give a really decent answer. As I said, interesting question. +1

Comment: Right, your results seem to agree with the .Net table. Doubling sample size doubles the number of removals, so for an `O(1)` hash table we expect running time to increase x2 for more deletions & x1 for no change in time per deletion, so twice as long. For an ArrayList, the number of deletions doubles, as does time for each deletion (`O(n)`). So execution time quadruples. Your data fits with that. Although I think the test would be more clear if you kept number of *c* constant and only varied *n* to test complexity of deletions, and vice-versa to test complexity of the filter method.

Comment: Yes to the first part about O. The last part...I am playing catch-up. How should I adapt the tests? n I am guessing is number of rows. c?  I will re-run and update post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170952/discussion-between-greedo-and-qharr).